# Is it possible to create a dictionary in which values can have multiple data types? (Also how do I iterate through an array as one of my values)

Tags: c#, dictionary

How do I iterate through profile["Names"] in this scenario?

using System.Collections.Generic;

```
        Dictionary<object, object> profile = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        profile.Add("Names", new string[]{"Joel", "Sean"});
        profile.Add("Ethnicity", "Asian");
        profile.Add("Language", "English");

        for (int i = 0; i < profile["Names"].length; i ++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"Name: {i}");
        }
       Console.WriteLine("Ethnicity - " + profile["Ethnicity"]);
       Console.WriteLine("Language - " + profile["Language"]);
```

Comment: It seems you've already answered both of your questions because you wrote the code would appear to solve it. Are you having some sort of problem with this code? If so, you need to describe what errors you're getting and/or how the execution differs from what you desire.

Comment: You can use pattern-matching feature of C# by writing something like: switch(profile["Names"]) case string[] ... case string ... case SqlConnection and so on. Also, have a look at Hashtable, it is non-generic version of Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use this where the key of the dictionary is type of string.

We need to cast the value object into string array when you know it is that.

```
Dictionary<string, object> profile = new Dictionary<string, object>();
profile.Add("Names", new string[] { "Joel", "Sean" });
profile.Add("Ethnicity", "Asian");
profile.Add("Language", "English");

var names = (string[])profile["Names"];
for ( int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++ )
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Name: {names[i]}");
}
Console.WriteLine("Ethnicity - " + profile["Ethnicity"]);
Console.WriteLine("Language - " + profile["Language"]);
```

But you should consider to rethink your design because the actual is not very clean not stringly typed.

Perhaps:

```
using System.Collections.Generics;

public class Profile
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
  public string Language { get; set; }
  public Profile(string name, string ethnicity, string language)
  {
    Name = name;
    Ethnicity = ethnicity;
    Language = language;
  }
}

var profiles = new List<Profile>();
profiles.Add(new Profile("Joel", "Asian", "English"));
profiles.Add(new Profile("Sean", "Asian", "English"));

foreach ( var item in profiles )
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("Ethnicity: " + item.Ethnicity);
  Console.WriteLine("Language: " + item.Language);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can also use enums or lookup collections instead of string for ethnicity and language:

```
enum Ethnicity
{
  Asian,
  Caucasian
}

enum Language
{
  English,
  French
}
```

Now a profile can be:

```
public class Profile
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
  public Language Language { get; set; }
  public Profile(string name, Ethnicity ethnicity, Language language)
  {
    Name = name;
    Ethnicity = ethnicity;
    Language = language;
  }
}
```

Used like that:

```
var profiles = new List<Profile>();
profiles.Add(new Profile("Joel", Ethnicity.Asian, Language.English));
profiles.Add(new Profile("Sean", Ethnicity.Asian, Language.English));

foreach ( var item in profiles )
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("Ethnicity: " + item.Ethnicity);
  Console.WriteLine("Language: " + item.Language);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```